# Installing basemap

Tags: python, installation, matplotlib-basemap

There are some pretty helpful links in [installing basemap](http://gnperdue.github.io/yak-shaving/osx/python/matplotlib/2014/05/01/basemap-toolkit.html) for python, however I seem to be encountering an issue towards the end of installation when trying to test if the installation has worked or not. I'm installing on a Mac.

The error message I'm seeing is:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % locale name
```

Admittedly I'm still not savvy with knowing my way around Macs and installing the anaconda suite took me a while to figure out. In my .profile file I added the following lines:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
epxort LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Still didn't change anything. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you have a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`? If so, those will be loaded and your `.profile` will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set the locale of python before importing basemap

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
```

Comment: Giovois, Thank you for that, it seemed to do the trick! Since I executed this command in terminal, when it comes to acutally coding in my Eclipse environment, do I need to execute these lines again, or since it's already been executed in terminal it is not necessary?
It's still not clear why I had import errors initially due to numpy and matplotlib, despite already having installed the anacanda package. After instaling numpy and matplotlib the problem was resolved.

Comment: Now on the MBP (the iMac installed fine in the end, thanks to the last tip), I have the following error message: `Command "cc nad2bin.o src/pj_malloc.o -o nad2bin" failed with exit status 1`

Comment: Hi, you should import it everytime you run it. You can add it in your matplotlib. I suggest you open another question with your mistake, I'll search for it and try to reproduce it.

Comment: Installing this worked on my iMac, but so far not on my MBP. I'd to like to deinstall this then reinstall. Is there a particular process to follow for deinstalling python libraries?